# C# Word Frequency using Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to find the word frequency of a text file using a dictionary, however I am having trouble creating the key and value for the dictionary.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader inputFile; //read the file 
        string words; //hold words from file
        int wordCount; //keep track of times words are repeated 

        //create dictionary 
        Dictionary<string, int> wordFrequency = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        //open file 
        inputFile = File.OpenText("Kennedy.txt");

        //read lines from file  
        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            words = inputFile.ReadLine();
            wordFrequency.Add(words, wordCount); //add elements to dictionary?

            //add words to list box
            lstboxwords.Items.Add(words); 
        }
```

Comment: Somewhere in there you probably need to split the lines into words. The words need to get either matched with `Dictionary` entries so their counts can be updated or added to the `Dictionary` if they are new words. The first part is hard, e.g. handling punctuation marks, and the second is easy. ("Why a duck?", "Duck Soup.", "Duck!", "A duck, a wallaby and a ferret walk into a bar ... ." How many ducks?)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing the part that splits the line into words.

You can do this with `string.Split`.  Then you need to iterate over the words within each line, and then add each word to the dictionary.

In pseudo code:

```
line = inputFile.ReadLine(); // Read the whole line
words = line.Split(' '); // Split the line into words
foreach(var word in words)
{
   if(!wordFrequency.ContainsKey(word)) // Do we already know about this word?
   {  
       wordFrequency.Add(word, 0); // It's a new word
   }
   wordFrequency[word]++; // Increment the count for each word
}
```